# File checker in bat

Tags: file, batch-file, select

okay so what i'd like to do is to check

1. is the script opened with a file? (drag'n'drop)
2. is the file's name "paths.ini"?

my problem is that i don't know WHERE the error is because it closes right away.

```
if [%1] NEQ [] (

    for /f %%i IN ("%1") do (
        set OPENWNAME=%%~ni
        set OPENWEXT=%%~xi
    )

    set OPENW=%OPENWNAME%%OPENWEXT%

    set FILENAME="paths.ini"

    if NOT %OPENW%=%FILENAME% (
        echo The file you selected is not paths.ini
        pause
        exit
    ) else (            
        echo You selected paths.ini
        pause
        goto Next
    )
)
```

i know it's stupid to post code and expect people to fix it for you but if i could specify my mistake i would google it :D

i bet i made an obvious mistake but i just can't see it. thanks in advance.

Comment: you used a single `=` in your `if` - wrong syntax. See `if /?` (should have been `==` or `EQU`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this:

```
if "%~n1%~x1" EQU "paths.ini" (
echo You selected paths.ini
pause
goto Next
) else (
echo The file you selected is not paths.ini
pause
exit
)
```

Done!